# Why Redis connection works from C# without specifying credentials?

Tags: c#, redis

Why Redis connection works from C# without specifying credentials? I have this code working and connected to remote server. My client machine is windows and REMOTE-MACHINE is Linux server. Does this means anyone in my LAN can connect?

```
 public class RedisConnectorHelper
    {                
        static RedisConnectorHelper()
        {
            RedisConnectorHelper.lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
            {
              return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("REMOTE-MACHINE");
            });
        }

        private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> lazyConnection;        

        public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection
        {
            get
            {
                return lazyConnection.Value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `redis-cli` also works without credentials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Redis Security](http://redis.io/topics/security) page:

> Redis is designed to be accessed by trusted clients inside trusted environments. This means that usually it is not a good idea to expose the Redis instance directly to the internet or, in general, to an environment where untrusted clients can directly access the Redis TCP port or UNIX socket.

Some very basic authentication with a password stored in the configuration file is provided but as the docs describe it, `it provides a tiny layer of authentication`.

Security has to be implemented at the network level with firewalls, port blocking, SSL. Redis itself doesn't provide SSL but you can use an SSL proxy, Cloud providers like Amazon and Azure for example, put an SSL proxy in front of their clusters.

Redis clients like [StackExchange.Redis](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis) support SSL, eg by setting `ssl=true` in the [connection string](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/Docs/Configuration.md)

Answer (score 2):

The default behavior of Redis allows it to accept connections without specifying any credentials to do so. If you want to change this then modify the Redis .conf file to configure it more to your liking. As far as your LAN question, I have no idea how your network is configured so I really can't answer that for you.

Comment: The docs warn though that this is a very weak security measure - the passwords are stored in the config file. It is assumed that server-to-server connections should be secured at the network level, using firewalls, blocking ports, server certificates etc.